# Function __asm__ __volatile__("rdtsc");

Tags: c++, x86, rdtsc

I don't know what exactly does this code:

```
int rdtsc(){
    __asm__ __volatile__("rdtsc");
```

Please, someone can explain me? why "rdtsc"?

Comment: Why downvoted? A similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56940066/rdtsc-a-a0-d-d0-what-does-this-do is upvoted.

Answer (score 11):

Actually, that's not very good code at all.

`RDTSC` is the x86 instruction "ReaD TimeStamp Counter" - it reads a 64-bit counter that counts up at every clock cycle of your processor.

But since it's a 64-bit number, it's stored in `EAX` (low part) and `EDX` (high part), and if this code is ever used in a case where it is inlined, the compiler doesn't know that `EDX` is being clobbered.  Or that the inline assembly sets EAX before falling off the end of a non-`void` function.

The compiler doesn't "understand" the assembler code, it's a black box which you must describe with input/output operands so it knows there's an output in `EDX:EAX`.  (Or an output in `EAX` with `EDX` being clobbered). I would do this:

```
uint64_t rdtsc()
{
   uint32_t hi, lo;
   __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=a"(lo), "=d"(hi));
   return ( (uint64_t)lo)|( ((uint64_t)hi)<<32 );
}
```

thus giving a time-count that doesn't wrap around every second or two on a modern machine, and which tells the compiler which registers your `asm` statement modifies.

Or use the `__rdtsc()` intrinsic to get the compiler to emit the `rdtsc` instruction itself, and know where the outputs are.  See [Get CPU cycle count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772567/get-cpu-cycle-count/51907627#51907627).

Comment: Comment from another user: you're missing a parenthesis in the last code block

Comment: why does "=a", and "=d" work in assembly? how does it know to refer to eax/edx?

Comment: The first colon in an `asm` statement describes the "output parameters", the register naming is described in the x86 part of the gcc inline assembler syntax. You can use google to search for that syntax - there are several different pages describing gcc x86 syntax.

Comment: No need for C-style casts here. Plain `uint64_t(hi) << 32 | lo` does it nicely.

Answer (score 7):

The often-cited inline assembly for `rdtsc` produces [supeflous code with gcc-7 and earlier versions](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48877).

A more efficient solution is to use `__builtin_ia32_rdtsc` built-in function:

```
uint64_t tsc = __builtin_ia32_rdtsc();
```